# Android: Save two Bitmaps with same name in internal storage

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap, internal-storage

If I save a Bitmap called "picture.jpg" in internal storage and some steps later I save another Bitmap called "picture.jpg" too, what happens then?
Does the second Bitmap overwrite the first or are there two Bitmaps with the same name then?

Comment: You **can't have** two files with the same name and same extension. If the file is open, you'll get an error, else it's overwritten by the new one.

Comment: So the second Bitmap will overwrite the first? That would be good.

Comment: If the first is **not already open** in some context. Or you'll get an error (which you can intercept and manage).

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/63118912/4685284

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will show you an error, I suggest you could use a dynamic file name or delete it before saving, in the case of dynamic, you could use something like this:

```
static int fCount = 0;

File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + File.separator + "/test" + String.valueOf(fCount++) +".jpg" );
```

Or

```
File file = new File(getExternalCacheDir(), "test.jpg" ); if (file.exists()) { boolean deleted = file.delete(); }
```